# jni4net in c#--Why did not java.util.List list= new java.util.ArrayList();

Tags: list, arraylist, jni4net

java.util.List list= new java.util.ArrayList(); // error in c#

List list= new ArrayList();// java

only: Hashtable hashtable=new Hashtable(); //ok in c#

Comment: I don't fully understand the question. Could you edit it to make it a bit clearer please?

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, Jni4net does not define by default a .Net proxy for java.util.ArrayList, but it does for java.util.List. If you want your code to work, you need to generate yourself a proxy for ArrayList using the proxigen tool.